Why I'm not getting any result (0 rows) for this query?
1st part is working. I am getting weekdays but when I run whole query I get 'No rows',even though there are orders on Monday. I can't figure out where is the problem. Please help me if anyone can solve it.
WITH cte1
     AS (SELECT o.order_id,
                p.price * o.quantity          AS total_spending,
                to_char (install_date, 'Day') AS weekday
         FROM   orders AS o
                LEFT JOIN parts AS p using (part_id)
                LEFT JOIN installs AS i
                       ON o.order_id = i.order_id)
SELECT *
FROM   cte1
WHERE  weekday = 'Monday' 


@JeJe from to_char (install_date, 'Day') as weekday

What happen if you remove the WHERE clause?

Better to use EXTRACT(DOW FROM install_date) to get the number of the weekday. This avoids all decencies on language settings, spaces, etc. Monday is the first day of the week, day 1. You could also use ISODOW when you need the numbering from 1 to 7 instead of 0 to 6 for DOW.

I would avoid using text comparison for the day of the week. Use extract(dow from install_date) instead to get a number.

Perhaps just looking at the documentation  would help: Day  |   full capitalized day name (blank-padded to 9 chars)  When having trouble it is always a good place to start. Postgres has extensive documentation: use it.

When i do the length for this to_char(current_date) i am getting 9 as the length whereas the length of Monday is 6,hence i did a TRIM and it worked.SQL fiddle here
WITH cte1
 AS (SELECT o.order_id,
            p.price * o.quantity          AS total_spending,
            to_char (install_date, 'Day') AS weekday
     FROM   orders AS o
            LEFT JOIN parts AS p using (part_id)
            LEFT JOIN installs AS i
                   ON o.order_id = i.order_id)
 SELECT *
 FROM   cte1
 WHERE  TRIM(weekday) = 'Monday' 

